# How do to make such a design with Android,and how do I put the shadow?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

How do to make [such button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFLNH.png) design with Android. And how do I put the shadow?

Comment: Image icon or text?

Comment: create a ring using drawable with a solid color as a blue one.
then  in your layout took imageview and background as drawable ( just create one)
create mic icon from vector asset and set image src

Comment: image icon @Piyush

Answer (score 0):

You can use floating action button to achieve this kind of design. [Example here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button)

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:elevation="10dp"` to set shadow for your view

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:background="Your_icon"/>
```